# Handling private messages discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

How I can handle all private messages in discord.py ?
i want to know if there is a way to reply same message to all private messages for example "you can't use commands in private messages"
I know functions are raising an error when messages are private but i don't want to use try and except for each function

also it would be better if only help command can be used in private

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `discord.ext.commands` you can start it with this

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.guild_only()
async def something(ctx):
......
```

regarding the help command you can let him type the command in the server and return it to him in private. This will add reaction with ✅ and send him the embed with all the help in private

```py
bot.remove_command("help")

@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Help")

    embed.set_footer(
        text="Enjoy, in case of issues contact AZ#0573")
    await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)
    await ctx.message.add_reaction("✅")
```

Answer (score 1):

Replase client to bot, if you want it

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id != client.user.id:
        if message.guild:  # If message in guild
            await client.process_commands(message)  # Process command
        else:
            return await message.author.send("Sorry, but i dont process commands on direct messages...")
```